# Parser rule is ignored in ANTLR grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr

I am trying to write my first ANTLR grammar. And I am parsing following test example:

```
token1 token2 
chapter1 token3 token4 token5 
chapter2 
token6 token7
chapter3 token8
```

And using following grammar:

```
    grammar Chapters;

message :   chapter+ EOF
    ;   


chapter :   (chapter1|chapter2|chapter3) text
    ;

text    :   ~(chapter1|chapter2|chapter3)*
    ;   

chapter1    :   'chapter1'
        ;   

chapter2    :   'chapter2'
        ;   

chapter3    :   'chapter3'
        ;   




Id  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

Int :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

Float
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* EXPONENT?
    |   '.' ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT?
    |   ('0'..'9')+ EXPONENT
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

Char:  '\'' ( ESC_SEQ | ~('\''|'\\') ) '\''
    ;

fragment
EXPONENT : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? ('0'..'9')+ ;

fragment
HEX_DIGIT : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
ESC_SEQ
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UNICODE_ESC
    |   OCTAL_ESC
    ;

fragment
OCTAL_ESC
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UNICODE_ESC
    :   '\\' 'u' HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT HEX_DIGIT
    ;
```

And I get following result:
[image: ANTLRWorks result]

What I wanted to see was **token1** and **token2** under **text** node, same goes for tokens 3,4 and 5 etc. So I wanted to break content under each chapter node into chapter name and chapter text. How should I change my grammar to achieve this?

Comment: Not necessarily related to your question, but the example text doesn't seem correct for the grammar. A `message` starts out with a chapter heading ("chapter1", etc) followed by text (non-chapter heading), but "token1 token2" doesn't begin with a chapter heading. If you're using ANTLRWorks, is it giving you an error?

Comment: I did everything inside ANTLRWorks and it worked without errors. But I decided to double check this and it looks like when I run this in Interpreter I get picture from my question and when I run it in debugger I get error. I've heard that ANTLRWorks is buggy but didn't believe it till now :(

Comment: Ok. The tree structure is ANTLRWorks's understanding of your grammar as it pertains to the given input. It's not a meaningful output tree (your grammar isn't producing AST, for one thing). I can go into more detail in an answer if you want. Otherwise, just know that the interpreter is misleading.

Comment: @tenterhook Thanks for comments. I didn't get to AST yet. I am using Parse Tree view in interpreter and debugger. I believe I should correct my grammar to work with debugger and then build AST, and if problem still exist, I'll update my question with new grammar code.